# Start and pause a process in python

Tags: python

I have a function that calculates the Fibonacci numbers. I am trying to add a feature that sends a signal indicating that I need to pause the function running. Once I get the signal, I store away all the numbers calculated thus far.

And when the user wants to resume the function, I can load back the files and start calculating from where we had stopped.

This is the code I have

```
MAX = 100000
fibo_series = [0] * MAX
import pickle

def fib(start_value=0, stop_value=1000, stop_signal=False):
    if not stop_signal:
        for i in range(start_value, stop_value):
            if i == 0:
                fibo_series[i] = 0
            elif i == 1 or i == 2:
                fibo_series[i] = 1
            else:
                fibo_series[i] = fibo_series[i-1] + fibo_series[i-2]
        return fibo_series[i]
    else:
        with open('fibo_series.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(fibo_series, f)

def reload_fib():
    with open('fibo_series.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        fibo_series = pickle.load(f)
    start_value = fibo_series[1:].index(0) + 1
    stop_value = len(fibo_series)
    return fib(start_value, stop_value, stop_signal=False)
```

The part that I am not able to figure out is how to use this `stop_signal` once the function has started running. Once the function has started the value `stop_signal` is locked. The only way I know to pause a function is by terminating it which is not what I am trying to do.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Not only is `stop_signal` "locked", but your function isn't even checking it once it starts running. You need to have the function check the signal in every iteration of the loop, and make the signal you check an external resource, such as the existence of a file or similar rather than an in-process variable. (If you are on a Unix-like system, you can use OS signals for this purpose.)

Comment: This is where you can use Threading. Run your code as a separate thread , where you can control its execution from outside.

Comment: @user4815162342, yes that's my bad. Checking before every iteration makes more sense.

Comment: @Kris, thanks for the suggestion. I'll look this up

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the stop and run conditions, but a simple work around is to use a global variable for these two functions. This is not better than using a lock of a thread library but if your work is simply to use one process and does not need complexity, then you may try.

```
import threading
import time


MAX = 100000
fibo_series = [0] * MAX
import pickle

stop_signal = False
def fib(start_value=0, stop_value=1000):
    for i in range(start_value, stop_value):
        if (not stop_signal):
            print('here', i)
            time.sleep(1)
            if i == 0:
                fibo_series[i] = 0
            elif i == 1 or i == 2:
                fibo_series[i] = 1
            else:
                fibo_series[i] = fibo_series[i-1] + fibo_series[i-2]
        else:
            break
    return fibo_series[i]
    print('exiting... stop_signal: ', stop_signal)
    with open('fibo_series.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(fibo_series, f)

def reload_fib():
    with open('fibo_series.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        fibo_series = pickle.load(f)
    start_value = fibo_series[1:].index(0) + 1
    stop_value = len(fibo_series)
    global stop_signal
    stop_signal = False
    return fib(start_value, stop_value)

x = threading.Thread(target=fib )
x.start()
time.sleep(10)

stop_signal = True

print('finished...')
```

Then, whenever the user wants to stop the execution, you can set the global variable `stop_signal=True`

and the output is:

```
here 0
here 1
here 2
here 3
here 4
here 5
here 6
here 7
here 8
here 9

finished...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: once execution is started, how would you set the value to True?

Comment: thanks, I have made a change to the code, and included threads. Also I have put an example output.